# How to measure correctly efficiency at high load with LT8646

Tags: power, power-electronics, buck

i'm trying to measure efficiency of a LT Part LT8646 at high load with the attached schematic. [image: LT8646 EVM]

i'm using a dynamic load and a power supply to give 12V. I'm using a digital multimeter to read the input current and find the efficiency. What i'm experiencing is a drop of the output voltage when the current is greater than 3A. I know this is due to the measurement setup, is there a method to avoid this and doing a correct measurement? Thanks

Comment: Use a load of precise value and calculate the current based on the load voltage.

Comment: what do you mean? can you explain better?

Comment: Do you measure the **input** current as you write or the **output** current? In case of input current, can you describe why the measurement setup causes a drop of the **output** voltage? Is it  because the input voltage drops? Why not measure the **input** voltage after this input current measurement?

Answer (score 0):

A way to get around this would be to use a sense resistor, maybe one with 0.01Ω. The sense resistor is placed between the load and the DC to DC converter. Then connect the DMM to the leads and measure the voltage. 6A would give you 0.06V and allow you to still measure with the DMM in mV mode.